How to make an array of protocols with a common associated type?
I have a simple protocol like so:
protocol Updater {
    associatedtype T

    func update(thing: T)
}

I would like to do the following, but I get the error Member 'update' cannot be used on value of type 'any Updater'; consider using a generic constraint instead:
class SomeGeneralUIComponent {
    var updaters: [any Updater] = [...]
}

// elsewhere in codebase
uiComponent.updaters.forEach {
    $0.update(thing: someThing)
}

This makes sense, because it doesn't know that all the Updaters in my array have the same associated type, I need to declare that somehow. So I attempted to follow the error's advice and make the class that contains the updaters array generic like so:
class SomeGeneralUIComponent<T> {
    typealias MyUpdater: Updater where Updater.T == T  // Error thrown here

    let updaters: [MyUpdater]
}

But I get the error Cannot access associated type 'T' from 'Updater'; use a concrete type or generic parameter base instead, and I'm not sure how to resolve that.
Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there any way to have an array of a protocol where you specify that they all share the same associated type?

Updater can have T as its primary associated type:
protocol Updater<T> {
    associatedtype T

    func update(thing: T)
}

Then you can write:
class SomeGeneralUIComponent<T> {
    let updaters: [any Updater<T>]

    // ...
}


I don't like that approach, because I need to decide what to use any Updater<T> or some Updater<T>

@Cy-4AH What's wrong with needing to decide that?

It's too confusing

@Cy-4AH That's a valid opinion. IMO though, it's not confusing once you understand what they mean.

I understand that with [some Updater<T>] it will work like generic, generic with big restrictions, so there is another confusion why to use some instead of generics.

This doesn't work using [any Updater<T>] because I still get the error Member 'update' cannot be used on value of type 'any Updater'; consider using a generic constraint instead when calling uiComponent.updaters.forEach { $0.update(thing: someThing }. If I try to do [some Updater<T>], then SomeGeneralUIComponent doesn't even compile that line, it gives the error Property declares an opaque return type, but cannot infer the underlying type from its initializer expression. I also think it wouldn't work anyway because it would restrict Updater type, not just T type.

@NewShelbyWoo please show a [mre] of that first error. What is the type of someThing?

@NewShelbyWoo For example, if I have a SomeGeneralUIComponent<Int>, I can write component.updaters.foreach { $0.update(thing: 1) } without any error. I cannot reproduce the error you got, and your problem probably lies somewhere else.

in my case someThing is something like struct ModelState { var memberState: SomeEnum }. I'll write a complete minimal reproducible example when I have some time later tonight.

@NewShelbyWoo Okay, then you should have a SomeGeneralUIComponent<ModelState>. If you don't/can't have that for whatever reason, I'd suggest posting a new question, explaining the broader picture of what you are doing and why you cannot create a SomeGeneralUIComponent<ModelState>.

@NewShelbyWoo If someThing can be a struct, then update should really be taking an inout T, or else it cannot possibly change the value of memberState.

That's true, I forgot the inout in my original question. I'll write up a better example.

Ok, working through a minimal example I discovered my issue. You were right @Sweeper, the problem was elsewhere. My UI component was returning the array by firing an event from an event enum and I had missed updating the case type to [any Updater<T>] instead of [any Updater]. Thank you very much for your help.

You can use type erasure to acheive your goal:
protocol Updater {
    associatedtype T

    func update(thing: T)
}

extension Updater {
    func eraseToAnyUpdater() -> AnyUpdater<T> {
        AnyUpdater(value: self)
    }
}

struct AnyUpdater<U>: Updater {
    typealias T = U
    
    var _update: (U) -> Void
    
    init<K: Updater>(value: K) where K.T == U {
        _update = {
            value.update(thing: $0)
        }
    }
    
    func update(thing: U) {
        _update(thing)
    }
}


class SomeGeneralUIComponent<T> {
    let updaters: [AnyUpdater<T>]
    
    init(updaters: [AnyUpdater<T>]) {
        self.updaters = updaters
    }
}

struct UpdaterInt: Updater {
    func update(thing: Int) {
        
    }
}

struct UpdaterSecondInt: Updater {
    func update(thing: Int) {
        
    }
}

let uiComponent = SomeGeneralUIComponent(updaters: [UpdaterInt().eraseToAnyUpdater(), UpdaterSecondInt().eraseToAnyUpdater()])
uiComponent.updaters.forEach {
    $0.update(thing: 0)
}

